# getting a single const char * in c

Tags: c, char

I'm trying to get the individual chars from the day of the week. Here is what I have.

```
const char *daysOfTheWeek[] = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
const char *tc = daysOfTheWeek[dayOfWeek];
text_layer_set_text(&dow_one, &tc[0]);
text_layer_set_text(&dow_two, &tc[1]);
text_layer_set_text(&dow_three, &tc[2]);
```

what is showing up is
&dow_one = ...
&dow_two = ed
&dow_three = d

What I want is
&dow_one = W
&dow_two = e
&dow_three = d

If i remove the & and just use tc[0] i get a compile error.

83:9: error: passing argument 2 of 'text_layer_set_text' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
/Users/myke/pebble_dev/pebble-sdk-release-001/watches/iWatch/include/pebble_os.h:677:6: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'

This is an embeded system that does not have access to sprintf. Pure C only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code you are pointing to a place "in the middle of the string" (for example, `&tc[1]` is a pointer to "this string called `tc`, but starting at location [1]"), and from there you get "everything until the end (the `'\0'` terminator)". If you want just one character, you should copy the individual strings to a null terminated string of length 1+1:

```
static char dow1[2];
static char dow2[2];
static char dow3[2];
char tc[]="Wed";

dow1[0] = tc[0]; dow1[1]='\0';
dow2[0] = tc[1]; dow2[1]='\0';
dow3[0] = tc[1]; dow3[1]='\0';
```

This is assuming that `tc` contains the characters you are interested in. Now you can do

```
text_layer_set_text(&dow_one, dow1);
text_layer_set_text(&dow_two, dow2);
text_layer_set_text(&dow_three, dow3);
```

Taking advantage of the fact that `dow1` is the name of the char array, and also the pointer to the first element. Per your own comment, I am declaring them as `static` - this means that the variable continues to exist after the function in which it was declared returns, and I imagine that's important since the value might be referenced later for display purposes.

Of course, if you really just need a character, it is simply

```
char c1, c2, c3;
c1 = tc[0];
c2 = tc[1];
c3 = tc[2];
```

It depends a bit on how you want to use it - not clear from your question what your `text_layer_set_text()` function does. I googled around a bit and I think the above should be OK for you - but I've not used Pebble so I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: It complies but doesn't have any data being displayed. I'm not sure if it has to do with what text_layer_set_text is expecting.  

void text_layer_set_text(TextLayer *text_layer, const char *text);

Comment: I assume you made sure that `tc` contains the string of interest... I didn't make that explicit, will edit answer.

Comment: I had that, I found the problem I was having. It needed to be static char dow.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad I was able to provide some help - and even more glad that ultimately you were able to solve your own problem! I will update the answer - makes it easier for the next person.